# method to go up and down an elevator in c #

Tags: c#

A few days ago I asked a question about threads, I managed to make part of a program for an elevator. I feel frustrated since I cannot make a method to stop the elevator if it goes to the 10th floor and I want to stop it at the 8th for example. any advice?

Here is my code.

```
namespace Elevador
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const string QUIT = "q";

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        
        Start:
            Console.WriteLine("¡Bienvenido a este ascensor");
            Console.WriteLine("¿Qué altura tiene el edificio en el que estará este ascensor?");

            int floor; string floorInput; Elevator elevator;

            floorInput = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Int32.TryParse(floorInput, out floor))
                elevator = new Elevator(floor);
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Eso no tiene sentido ...");
                Console.Beep();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.Clear();
                goto Start;
            }
            string input = string.Empty;

            while (input != QUIT)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Por favor presione a qué piso le gustaría ir");

                input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Int32.TryParse(input, out floor))
                    elevator.FloorPress(floor);
                else if (input == QUIT)
                    Console.WriteLine("adios");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Ha presionado un piso incorrecto. Vuelva a intentarlo.");
            }
        }
    }


    public class Elevator
    {
        // Incumplimientos y declaraciones
// el edificio tiene n pisos

        private bool[] floorReady;
        public int CurrentFloor = 1;
        private int topfloor;
        public ElevatorStatus Status = ElevatorStatus.STOPPED;

        public Elevator(int NumberOfFloors = 10)
        {
            floorReady = new bool[NumberOfFloors + 1];
            topfloor = NumberOfFloors;
        }

        private void Stop(int floor)
        {
            Status = ElevatorStatus.STOPPED;
            CurrentFloor = floor;
            floorReady[floor] = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Detenido en el piso {0}", floor);
        }

        private void Descend(int floor)
        {
            for (int i = CurrentFloor; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                if (floorReady[i])
                    Stop(floor);
                else
                    continue;
            }

            Status = ElevatorStatus.STOPPED;
            Console.WriteLine("Esperando..");
        }

        private void Ascend(int floor)
        {
            for (int i = CurrentFloor; i <= topfloor; i++)
            {
                if (floorReady[i])
                    Stop(floor);
                else
                    continue;
            }

            Status = ElevatorStatus.STOPPED;
            Console.WriteLine("Esperando..");
        }

        void StayPut()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ese es nuestro piso actual");
        }

        public void FloorPress(int floor)
        {
            if (floor > topfloor)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nosotros solo tenemos {0} pisos", topfloor);
                return;
            }

            floorReady[floor] = true;

            switch (Status)
            {

                case ElevatorStatus.DOWN:
                    Descend(floor);
                    break;

                case ElevatorStatus.STOPPED:
                    if (CurrentFloor < floor)
                        Ascend(floor);
                    else if (CurrentFloor == floor)
                        StayPut();
                    else
                        Descend(floor);
                    break;

                case ElevatorStatus.UP:
                    Ascend(floor);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }


        }

        public enum ElevatorStatus
        {
            UP,
            STOPPED,
            DOWN
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you should set STOPPED in your Stop unless the elevator has reached the floor that started its motion. When the elevator does reach that floor it should then scan the bool array to see if it has to move anywhere else and start going towards that floor if it does. I do think it's more complex than just having a List of floor levels and the elevator always travels towards the head of the list, and new button presses are inserted at the head if the elevator will reach them before it's current destination, or between two floors later in the list if it already missed the new floor

Comment: But if you want to stick with the bool your going to need a routine that starts at the current floor and scans in the direction of the current lift motion (perhaps it would be easiest to represent the motion as -1, 0, or 1) looking for any other bools, and only set stopped when there are no more bools in that direction, then scan in the other direction and if there are any bool in the other direction, flip to moving that way

Answer (score 0):

After calling `Stop(floor)` you need to break out of the `for` loop. You can use the `break` command to do that. But you probably want to check first if there are floors in the direction of travel that are still waiting for people.

Instead of a for loop you might find it easier to create a while loop that moves the elevator in the direction or travel until there's no reason to go that direction, then reverses and does the same the other way and so on until there is no work to do.

See also https://play.elevatorsaga.com/ as a good place to practice elevator algorithms.